# AJAX request - How can I see the request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have tried to send an AJAX request and wanted to see what I've send.
But unfortunately I'm not able to do it.
There exists a select option element that I will fill later with the response if everything works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select[name="domains"]').change(function(){
      var requestStr = $(this).val();

      // send Ajax request
      $.ajax({
         cache: 'false',
         type: 'POST',
         data: {select:requestStr},
         url: 'myHandler.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data){
    var json = JSON.parse(data);                    
            alert(json.response); // Here you get the value

    if(data.status == 'success')
       alert("Thank you for subscribing!");
    else if(data.status == 'error')
       alert("Error on query!");

            var str = "<option value=''>Please Select</option>";

            //$.each(data, function(i, items){
            //   str += "<option value='"+items.id+"'>"+items.name+"</options";
            //});

            $('select[name="countries"]').html( str );
         },
         // When an error occurs, the error function is called.
     error:function(x,e){
            if(x.status==0){
               alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
            }else if(x.status==404){
               alert('Requested URL not found.');
            }else if(x.status==500){
               alert('Internel Server Error.');
            }else if(e=='parsererror'){
               alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
            }else if(e=='timeout'){
               alert('Request Time out.');
            }else {
               alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
            }
         }                      
      });
   });
});
```

The PHP handler Looks like this:

```
<?php

require_once 'myClass.php';

if (isset($_POST['select']))
{
    // log event
$filename = "log.txt";
$fd = fopen($filename, "a");
$str = "[" . date("Y/m/d h:i:s", mktime()) . "] " . $_POST['select'];
fwrite($fd, $str . "\n");
    fclose($fd);

    $handler = new myClass();
    $dataAjax = $handler->getName($_POST['select']);
    echo json_encode($dataAjax);
}

<?php
class myClass {

   function getName($data)
   {
      return $data;
   }
}
```

I thought I can use the request parameter and return it but there is nothing I can see.
Oh, I use Internet Explorer so I can't use Firebug.

**EDIT**
I added a few rows to log my request.
But the log file is empty.

**UPDATE**
Now there is some progress:

I can see this in the request-text "select=QD".
But when I echo it with `echo json_encode($dataAjax);`
I get a error window with `Error.Parsing JSON Request failed.`

I don't get it why the 'success' function won't work!
The response is json encoded.

Oh btw. is it right that I can't use "return" in PHP to send my response back to AJAX?

Comment: IE has developer tools - F12 or F10 I believe (should be in the options -> dev tools) - from there, view your Network tab

Comment: Firebug (Firefox) <= My Favorite, Developer tools (Chrome)

Comment: Even if youre using internet explorer with how much it sucks, you can at least debug this with firebug or chrome console enough to get the ajax request working.

Comment: Ok, in the developer Tools under Network I can see the request but the answer is a normal "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" but with no Content. As written to @Andres Orav I guess I can't call my function or the return in my function has to wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can print out request at server side and log it into file/syslog/etc.

Comment: Ok, I tried to log it but there was no entry.
I guess I can't call a function inside a class with my construction.

Comment: Try to debug, for example try to log something else in higher level. Then, $data is in this situatsion an array, so you can try this way:
    $str = "[" . date("Y/m/d h:i:s", mktime()) . "] " . print_r($data, true);

Comment: Thank you Andres Orav. I have updated my Topic and code. But anyway the 'success'-function won't response only the 'error'-function.
I have encoded my response with JSON but AJAX says it is wrong.

Comment: You can allways emulate AJAX request in PHP side, so it prints out result. Good luck with debugging :)

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to see the `headers,post,response,html` then try [firebug](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/&ei=k5oNU8_mBMqHrAfznoGgAQ&usg=AFQjCNHvF9gBp-GpiLbrhdYmxpgw0WER9Q&sig2=luvvipRx7VVe4joa-02ahw&bvm=bv.61965928,d.bmk)

```
function IsJson(str) {
    try {
    JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

this will check whether the response is json or not

Comment: As commented top, I have only Internet Explorer. I know, bad. But that is firm policy.

Comment: then try f12 , this will show you all ajax requests

Comment: I do. I have updated my Topic and some of my code. Now it nearly works. But the 'success'-function don't response only the 'error'-function

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (isset($_POST['countries']))
 {
    $handler = new myClass();
    $dataAjax = $handler->getName($_POST['countries']);
    echo json_encode($dataAjax);
 }

 ------------------------------------------------------

 dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: Ok, now I get a resonse back. Or better I can see in the response text my HTML and at the end I see "QL" append to the end of my HTML.

Great! But why does my "success" function not working???
The "error" function in AJAX would return an "alert" but there is no alert window. And if it was a success my second select box should change ist values, at least the first value.

Don't understand that behavior. :-(